# TypeError: Service is not a function when calling API by angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Whenever I run the app implemented by angularjs 1.4.3.

BannerService.js

```
app.service('BannerService',function ($http) {

    this.save = function saveBanner(banner) {
        return $http({
              method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:8081/api/banners'
            });
    }

});
```

BannerController.js

```
app.controller('BannerAddCtrl', ['$scope','$log','BannerService',
    function ($scope,$log, BannerService) {
        $scope.save = function() {
            BannerService.saveBanner(myBanner)
                .success(function (result) {
                    $log.debug('RESULT', result);
                }, function (reason) {
                    $log.debug('REASON', reason);
                });
        }
```

}]);

And index.html

```
 <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-click="save()">Save Banner</button>

  </div>
```

It throws an exception as below:

```
TypeError: BannerService.saveBanner is not a function
at ChildScope.$scope.save (bannerControllers.js:64)
at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:13145), <anonymous>:4:203)
at callback (angular.js:23298)
at ChildScope.$eval (angular.js:15846)
at ChildScope.$apply (angular.js:15945)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:23303)
at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.js:4435)
at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4121)
```

Can someone help me why I get the error. Greatly appreciate your time.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at the error message:

```
BannerService.saveBanner is not a function
```

Basically, your app is looking for the property `saveBanner` assigned to your Service. But currently you haven't declared such a property. Instead your Service contains a property called `save` which defines a function (called saveBanner).

AngularJS doesn't care about a named function which is assigned to a property. So instead, you've to adjust the propertyname itself. So your Service's function/property should be like this.

```
this.saveBanner = function () { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks it is useful to me.

Comment: Glad I could help. Getting marked as correct answe would be nice though. :)

Answer (score 0):

Write your service like below.

```
var self = this;
self.saveBanner = function () { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're save function in the controller isn't actually calling the function in your service.

```
app.service('BannerService',function ($http) {
        return {
          saveBanner: function(banner) {
                return $http({
                      method: 'POST',
                        url: 'http://localhost:8081/api/banners'
                    });
                  }
               }
});
```